# Deep Neural Network weight initialization

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

Given *difficult* learning task (e.g high dimensionality, inherent data complexity) *Deep Neural Networks* become hard to train.
 To ease many of the problems one might:

1. Normalize && handpick *quality data*
2. choose a different *training algorithm* (e.g RMSprop instead of Gradient Descent)
3. pick a steeper gradient *Cost function* (e.g Cross Entropy instead of MSE)
4. Use different network structure (e.g Convolution layers instead of Feedforward)

I have heard that there are clever ways to initialize better weights. For example you can choose the magnitude better:
Glorot and Bengio (2010)

- for sigmoid units: sample a *Uniform(-r, r)* with $r =
     \sqrt{\frac{6}{N_{in} + N_{out}}}$
- or hyperbolic tangent units: sample a *Uniform(-r, r)* with $r =4
     \sqrt{\frac{6}{N_{in} + N_{out}}}$

Is there any consistent way of initializing the weights better?

Comment: Do not post [questions on multiple sites](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10926/how-to-deep-neural-network-weight-initialization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the two formulas you gave are pretty much the standard initialization. I did a [literature review](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/186351/12359) a while ago, please see my linked answer.

Comment: A potential editor suggests that the formulas for sigmoid and hyperbolic tangent be switched "to match the original paper".

Answer (score 3):

Recently, Batch Normalization was introduced for this sole purpose. Please find the paper [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167)

Comment: I am using this already. Is it enough by itself or maybe it can be further improved?

Comment: There were some extensions but i think this is the most popular one. I dont remember the exact name of the extensions. I think this should be enough also you can use a higher learning rate while optimizing.

Comment: I have seen adaptive weight opt. algorithms work a lot better. But thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The paper ['all you need is a good init'](http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06422) is a good relatively recent article about inits in deep learning. What I liked about it is that:

1. it has a short and effective literature survey on init methods, references included.
2. It achieves very good results without too many bells and whistles on cifar10.

Answer (score 1):

Weights initialization depend on the activation function being used. Xavier and Bengio(2010) derived a method for initializing weights based on the
assumption that the activations are linear. Their method resulted in the formula:
\begin{align}
W \sim U \left[ -\frac{\sqrt 6}{\sqrt {n_{i} + n_{i+1}}}, \frac{\sqrt 6}{\sqrt {n_{i} + n_{i+1}}} \right] 
\end{align}

For weights initialized using uniform distribution where $n_{i}$ represents $\text{fan in}$ and  $n_{i+1}$ represents $\text{fan out}$.

He, Kaiming, et al.(2015) used a derivation method that considered use of ReLUs as the activation function and obtain a weight initialization formula:

\begin{align}
W_l \sim \mathcal N \left({\Large 0}, \sqrt{\frac{2}{n_l}} \right).
\end{align}

For weights initialized using Gaussian distribution whose standard deviation (std) is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{n_l}}$

Read a more comprehensive series of articles covering Mathematics behind weights initialization [here](http://jefkine.com/deep/2016/08/08/initialization-of-deep-networks-case-of-rectifiers/).