# Best practice to find global maximum optimum

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, optimization

It there any best practice to select initial values when doing maximum likelihood estimation?

For the time being I'm generating series of initial values at random using for example a normal distribution mean=0 and sd = 10, and pick the initial values with the highest maximum likelihood. A question might be how many series to generate to guarantee the global maximum.  Yet this approach might be very time consuming.

I recently came across the following paper that suggest some test for global maximum oflikelihood function. But I have not yet implemented it.
http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~hero/Preprints/blatt_hero_icassp05.pdf

Comment: Look through https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=global+optimization+answers%3A1

Comment: When it comes to clever choices of initial values for optimization routines, it seems that much can be learned from the ML community https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/229669