# Why my weight Initialization saturates the activation function?

Tags: neural-networks, normalization, conv-neural-network

I am trying to initialize the Hidden Layers of my Convolutional Neural Network with 7 hidden layers, all with ELU Activation with Sigmoid Activation at the end for binary classification.

For Initialization of hidden layers, I've followed [He Initialization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01852.pdf) by equating the standard deviation to **`sqrt(2.0/n)`** where n is the number of neurons in the previous layer.

**What I find quite disturbing is that this initialization tends to saturate the output for *some of the observations in my mini-batch***, whereas following the "naive approach" and setting all standard deviations to 0.01 from a Gaussian Distribution avoids saturation for all observations (all outputs coming from the Sigmoid are approximately 0.5, which is ideal for SGD).

**My question is what is the cause of this saturation and what is the correct way of initialization? Is the "naive approach" for initialization flawed?**

I've also read through related [posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47590/what-are-good-initial-weights-in-a-neural-network) but am still puzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I observed empirically is that sampling from a truncated normal distribution rather than a standard normal distribution better prevents saturation at the output sigmoid. This might be due to a more constrained variance.